# Oracle: to_number() combined with substr() and regexp_like() in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, substr, regexp-like

I have a table with a column "description" which has the following values:

- OPTestMachine
- OPManualTesting
- OP1010

So the select statement, to get the values, would just be

```
SELECT description
  FROM operation;
```

I want to extract the number "1010" (or any string which matches the substr() criterion) and convert the "found string" into an integer if possible.

So I came up with this:

```
SELECT to_number(substr(description, 3, 4))
  FROM operation
 WHERE regexp_like(substr(description, 3, 4), '^\d+(\.\d+)?$', '')
```

The result is plain and simple: "1010"

That works pretty well for me.

Now the hard part for me: I want to use the substr()-result in the WHERE-clause

Something like this:

```
 SELECT to_number(substr(description, 3, 4))
   FROM operation
  WHERE regexp_like(substr(description, 3, 4), '^\d+(\.\d+)?$', '')
    AND substr(description, 3, 4) < 2000;
```

When I do this I get the error "Invalid number". I guess it is because of the order how the server is parsing the select statement.

If you could provide any help that'd be great!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `substr` function returns a string, and you have to explicitly cast it to number as you did in the select statement: 
`AND to_number(substr(description, 3, 4)) < 2000;`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have already tried this and it returns the same error "Invalid number"

Comment: My hunch here is that the substring returns something else than a number and it causes it to crash. Try trimming it in case it encounters spaces: `AND to_number(ltrim(rtrim(substr(description, 3, 4)))) < 2000;`

Comment: yeah, you are right! The second solution with trim works!

Comment: @rwur trim() is good solution but I'm not sure if you can rely on order of condition checking. So maybe adding another query is safer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT to_number(substr(description, 3, 4))
   FROM operation
  WHERE regexp_like(substr(description, 3, 4), '^\d+(\.\d+)?$', '')
    AND to_number(substr(description, 3, 4)) < 2000;
```

Does second to_number help?

if not I would do:

```
select to_number(x) from (
SELECT substr(description, 3, 4) x
       FROM operation
      WHERE regexp_like(substr(description, 3, 4), '^\d+(\.\d+)?$', ''))
        WHERE to_number(x) < 2000;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have already tried this and it returns the same error "Invalid number

Comment: @rwur second query as well? In that case what is your decimal separator?